# Mysql Add a new value to a column of data type enum

Tags: mysql, ddl

Say I have a mysql table, and I have a column of type `enum` and that column has defined set of values like `enum('a','b','c','d')`.

How would i add a value of `'e'` to this set using alter table statement?

And I want to append the new value to the end of it using `CONCAT`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to re-list all the existing enum values when adding a new value to the the enum.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN mycolumn ENUM('a','b','c','d','e');
```

You don't really want to use `CONCAT()` in this situation.

Comment: how to set default value in this statement. `SET DEFAULT 'a'` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to add default value and also want after a specific column for enum, try this query:

```
Alter table `your_table` 
Add column `visible_on` enum('web','mobile','both') default 'both' 
After `your_column`;
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.